# hadoop cassandra cpu utilization

Tags: performance, hadoop, cassandra

Summary:  How can I get Hadoop to use more CPUs concurrently on my server?

I'm running Cassandra and Hadoop on a single high-end server with 64GB RAM, SSDs, and 16 CPU cores.  The input to my mapreduce job has 50M rows. During the map phase, Hadoop creates seven mappers.  Six of those complete very quickly, and the seventh runs for two hours to complete the map phase.  I've suggested more mappers like this ...

job.getConfiguration().set("mapred.map.tasks", "12");

but Hadoop continues to create only seven.  I'd like to get more mappers running in parallel to take better advantage of the 16 cores in the server.  Can someone explain how Hadoop decides how many mappers to create?

I have a similar concern during the reduce phase.  I tell Hadoop to create 12 reducers like this ...

job.setNumReduceTasks(12);

Hadoop does create 12 reducers, but 11 complete quickly and the last one runs for hours.  My job has 300K keys, so I don't imagine they're all being routed to the same reducer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The map task number is depend on your input data.
For example:

- if your data source is HBase the number is the region number of you data
- if your data source is the file the map number is your file size/the block size(64mb or 128mb).

you cannot specify the map number in code

The problem of 6 fast and 1 slow is because the data unbalanced. I did not use Cassandra before, so I cannot tell you how to fix it.

Comment: Owen, thanks for your reply.  My input source is neither HBase nor files.  It's a Cassandra table.  I understand that you cannot tell Hadoop how many mappers to create, you can only suggest the number of mappers, and that's what I wrote in my post.  As it is, the job takes eight hours to complete, but most of that time, only one of my 16 CPUs is busy.  So I need to figure out how to get 12 or more mappers working in parallel and 12 or more reducers working in parallel.

Comment: maybe you can add concurrent ability in your mapper code. It will be much easier to control.